# Can we display parameters sent by response.sendRedirect on the next page. If yes, how?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, response.redirect, getparameter

Is this the correct way to display **parameter** sent by,

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?a="+1);

alert(<%=request.getParameter("a")%>);
```

Comment: it should be `response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?a=1");`

Answer (score 0):

```
response.sendRedirect("nextPage.jsp?paramName=someValue");
```

So on nextPage.jsp you have to write

```
String value = request.getParameter("paramName");
```

to get parameter value back.